# Both filling between two curves and orienting curves curves don't work at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How can I fix the code below to both fill area in between two curves and orient the curves?

```
\documentclass[10pt,thmsa]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{ decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

    \scalebox{0.6}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=12cm,axis equal image, xticklabel style={font=, below right}, 
 yticklabel style={font=, above right}, axis lines=middle,
                xmin=-0.5,xmax=1.7,
                ymin=-0.5,ymax=1.7,
                xtick={0,1},ytick= 
                {0,1},
                xticklabels={0,1},yticklabels= 
                {0,1},
                axis line style={very thick, latex-latex},
                axis line style={->},
                x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                    anchor=west,},
                y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                    anchor=south},
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$y$}
                ]
                \addplot[name path=A, very thick, samples=300, domain=-0.4:1.4, decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrowreversed[scale=1.5]{Straight Barb}}}, postaction=decorate] (x,x);
                \addplot[name path=B, very thick, samples=300, domain=-0.5:1.4, decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{Straight Barb}}}, postaction=decorate] (x,{x^2});
                \addplot[teal!50, opacity=0.45] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
                \draw[dashed] (1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1);
                \node [above] at (1.1,1.5) {$ y=x^2 $};
                \node [above] at (1.4,1.15) {$ y=x$};
                \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:.1,-.02) {$ 0$};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why, but the `postaction` ruins the path here - so just use a `preaction` like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,
axis equal,  axis lines=middle,
xmin=-0.5, xmax=1.7,
ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.7,
xtick={0,1}, ytick={0,1},
xticklabels={0,1}, yticklabels={0,1},
axis line style={very thick, latex-latex},
axis line style={->},
x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
anchor=west,},
y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
anchor=south},
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
]

\addplot[name path=A, very thick, samples=300, domain=1.4:-0.4, decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{Straight Barb}}}, preaction=decorate] (x,x);

\addplot[name path=B, very thick, samples=300, domain=-0.5:1.4, decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{Straight Barb}}}, preaction=decorate] (x,{x^2});

\addplot[teal!50, opacity=0.45] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:1}];

\draw[dashed] (1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1);
\node [above] at (1.1,1.5) {$ y=x^2 $};
\node [above] at (1.4,1.15) {$ y=x$};
\node [below] at (.1,-.02) {$ 0$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Two plots with filled area between]